# String printing in one line only and having a hard time understanding code. (TASM/DOSbox)

Tags: assembly, tasm, dosbox

So i am currently trying out my teachers instructions and are trying it out step by step. I even try to copy his errors so that i could see if my tasm works the same as his. Now we have a exercise where in we have to output cas in 3 different levels. Could someone please explain to me what these mean and how am i able to print the three "cas" in three levels diagonally from upper right to lower left?

```
.model small
.code
org 100h
start: jmp main
mess 1 db"CAS$"
mess 2 db"CAS$"
mess 1 db"CAS$"
main proc near
mov ax,03
int 10h

mov ah,05
mov bh,05
mov dh,05
mov dl,05
int 10h

mov ah,09
mov cx,03
mov bl,42h
int 10h

mov ah,09
mov dx,offset mess1
int 21h

mov ah,02
mov bh,00
mov dh,12
mov dl,40
int 10h

mov ah,09
mov cx,03
mov bl,42h
int 10h

mov ah,09
mov dx,offset mess2
int 21h

mov ah,02
mov bh,00
mov dh,12
mov dl,40
int 10h

mov ah,09
mov cx,03
mov bl,42h
int 10h

mov ah,09
mov dx,offset mess3

int 21h
int 20h
main endp
end start
```

Look, i really dont understand what i am doing here as i only followed my teachers work. He really didn't explain it very well and was just showing us the step by step process without explaining what and why he was doing it. The only thing i know here is cx is for number of characters and bh is background color of the text? hope someone can help me in my problem!

Look, i really dont understand what i am doing here as i only followed my teachers work. He really didn't explain it very well and was just showing us the step by step process without explaining what and why he was doing it. The only thing i know here is cx is for number of characters and bh is background color of the text? hope someone can help me in my problem!

Answer (score 0):

New lines don't happen by default. You need to manually add them in. My preferred way is to put them into the strings directly.

```
mess1 db "cas",13,10,'$'
mess2 db " cas",13,10,'$'
mess3 db "  cas",13,10,'$'
```

If you print these back to back you should get:

```
cas
 cas
  cas
```